# Magento 2: SMTP Email gives error "Invalid sender data"

Tags: magento2, php, email, wamp, send-mail

Using Magento 2 Version 2.1.0 on WAMP Windows 10

I'm using https://github.com/magepal/magento2-gmailsmtpapp

In magento Admin, then goto Stores -> Configuration -> Advanced -> System -> Gmail/Google Apps SMTP Pro.
I have configured things

- Authentication method: LOGIN
- SSL type: SSL (Gmail / Google Apps)
- SMTP Host: smtp.gmail.com
- Username: Gmail Account Username
- Password: GmailAccount Password
- Set Reply-to: Yes
- Set Return-Path: Yes

I have below code in my Controller

```
 $storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE;
        $transport = $this->_transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier(1)
                ->setTemplateOptions(['area' => \Magento\Backend\App\Area\FrontNameResolver::AREA_CODE, 'store' => 1])
                ->setTemplateVars(['data' => $postObject])
                ->setFrom('XXXX@gmail.com', $storeScope)
                ->addTo('XXXX@gmail.com', $storeScope)
                ->setReplyTo('XXXX@gmail.com')
                ->getTransport();
        echo $transport->sendMessage();
```

When i run this code, it gives below error

> 1 exception(s): Exception #0
>   (Magento\Framework\Exception\MailException): Invalid sender data

Now it's causing

> Could Not Open Socket

Comment: Does the default contact us form work?

Comment: @ankit ...i am getting same problems if you have solutions please paste here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to replace **`->setFrom('XXXX@gmail.com', $storeScope) to ->setFrom('XXXX@gmail.com')`** in above code, Becasue setFrom method is not supported two arguments.

Check core function for this, inside file, **magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Mail/Template/TransportBuilder.php**

```
public function setFrom($from)
    {
        $result = $this->_senderResolver->resolve($from);
        $this->message->setFrom($result['email'], $result['name']);
        return $this;
    }
```

if you want to pass storescope in your method, please refer core contact module mail functionality from here,
**magento2/vendor/magento/module-contact/Controller/Index/Post.php**

```
->setFrom($this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_SENDER, $storeScope))
```

Comment: Still issue, By changing it

Comment: you can change inside ->addTo('XXXX@gmail.com', $storeScope) to ->addTo('XXXX@gmail.com') remove var and check again

Comment: Its' solved "Invalid Sender Data" Issue not getting "Could Not Open Socket" issue